# Accumulate counts of a column's data values as separate columns

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I am trying to get a specific format of csv so another code can read it properly. I have ordered it using Ordereddicts but it takes much longer, and my plotting code is giving me "StringIO() takes no keyword arguments" error. Although I think I could probably fix that, I prefer my value_counts method anyway because it is much faster. I get a csv file with the correct information, the step I need next is just formatting. I've looked up multiple threads on similar issues but not how to sort this particular way.

My code:

```
import csv
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from collections import defaultdict, Counter
import pandas.util.testing as tm; tm.N = 3

data = pd.DataFrame.from_csv('MYDATA.csv')

data[['QualityIssue','CompanyName']]
data['QualityIssue'].value_counts()
RatedCustomerCallers = data['CompanyName'].value_counts()
TopCustomerCallers = RatedCustomerCallers[0:18]
print(TopCustomerCallers)

TopCustomerCallers.to_csv('topcustomercallerslist.csv')

byqualityissue = data.groupby(["CompanyName","QualityIssue"]).size()
print byqualityissue
byqualityissue.to_csv('byqualityissue.csv', header=True)
```

Output:

```
CompanyName,     QualityIssue,        0
Company 1,       Equipment Error,     15
Company 2,       User Error,          1
Company 2,       Equipment Error,     5
Company 3,       Equipment Error,     3
Company 3,       User Error,          10
Company 3,       Neither,             13
```

Where Company names are repeated for each type of issue.

However, I want it to be sorted by Top calling customers (added number of Equipment, User, Neither calls)  and display in this way:

```
Top Calling Customers,         Equipment,    User,    Neither,
Company 3,                      3,           10,        13,
Company 1,                      15,           0,        0,
Customer 2,                      5,           1,        0,
```

I tried using a pivot table

```
df = pd.DataFrame(byqualityissue)
df.pivot(index='CompanyName', columns='QualityIssue', values='0')
```

But it's giving me KeyError: '0' which is strange since I put that in for the input for values. Also, I am not sure it will work since each customer's output is only the type they called in. As in, Company 1 only had equipment error calls so it doesn't list them for User Error or Neither calls. Not sure if a pivot table will account for this.

Comment: You import `Counter` twice from `collections` and could you please fix the missing quotation mark in `data = pd.DataFrame.from_csv(MYDATA.csv')`.

Comment: Approved your edits, thanks. @Scironic

Comment: Look into Pivot Tables: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reshaping.html

Comment: @Plug4   Yes, this is the most logical way. However I have issues with first making it a dataframe: df = pd.DataFrame(byqualityissue)                                   df.pivot(index='CompanyName', columns='QualityIssue', values='0')                      next with KeyError: '0', and finally I'm not sure if a pivot table will work since each company only which calls it DID get, but doesn't necessarily label a zero for the types it did not get.

Comment: Wanted to comment, but am super busy so I can't elaborate much.. [unstack](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html?highlight=unstack#pandas.DataFrame.unstack) should help you in this situation.

Comment: @bdiamante Yes! This worked for me! The only thing I have to work out now is how to sort it for the top callers. This is how I used unstacked:
    formatted = df.unstack(level=-1)     \\\\\new line\\\\                     

    formatted[np.isnan(formatted)] = 0

Comment: @jenryb Glad you figured it out! For your sorting, I'd probably create a total column that is the sum of the other three and then do a descending sort on the total.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the spirit of StackOverflow, here is how I solved my issue.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pandas.util.testing as tm; tm.N = 3

data = pd.DataFrame.from_csv('MYDATA.csv')
byqualityissue = data.groupby(["CompanyName","QualityIssue"]).size()
df = pd.DataFrame(byqualityissue)

formatted = df.unstack(level=-1)
formatted[np.isnan(formatted)] = 0
formatted.to_csv('byqualityissue.csv', header=True)

includingtotals = pd.concat([formatted,pd.DataFrame(formatted.sum(axis=1),columns=['Total'])],axis=1)
sorted = includingtotals.sort_index(by=['Total'], ascending=[False])
```

I used unstack to reorganize my data, replaced NaN values with a 0, added up all the rows and appended a new column with those values, then sorted.

Answer (score 1):

Read your CSV file in. Index it by both Company and Quality Issue, then unstack it on Quality Issue. Finally, replace the `Nan` values that occur because no matching data were found

```
In [341]: d1
Out[341]:
    Company Name Quality Issue  Cases
0         Co 1     Equipment     15
1         Co 2          User      1
2         Co 2     Equipment      5
3         Co 3     Equipment      3
4         Co 3          User     10
5         Co 3       Neither     13

In [342]: d2 = d1.set_index(["Company Name", "Quality Issue"])

In [343]: d2
Out[343]:
                        Cases
Company Name Quality Issue
Co 1         Equipment         15
Co 2         User               1
             Equipment          5
Co 3         Equipment          3
             User              10
             Neither           13

In [344]: d3 = d2.unstack("Quality Issue")

In [345]: d3.fillna(0)
Out[345]:
    Cases
Quality Issue  Equipment  Neither  User
Company Name
Co 1                  15        0     0
Co 2                   5        0     1
Co 3                   3       13    10
```

Comment: Revisiting really quickly to ask: How did you name the size() column to be Cases? I am trying to name it but all I get is a 0.